# Separate text only up to the sixth bar in the value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

For values of this type:

```
https://int.testlink.com/international/europe/uefa-cup/20212022/3rd-qualifying-round/r63669/
```

I use this formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A,REGEXREPLACE(A1:A,"(https?:\/\/([\w.-]+\/){4})","($1)")))
```

To retrieve this type of value up to the sixth bar:

```
https://int.testlink.com/international/europe/uefa-cup/
```

But for this type of value it contains `@@@@` and `$$$$`:

```
https://int.testlink.com/national/scotland/third-division/@@@@/regular-season/$$$$/
```

The result is an error, I would like to know how I should modify it to carry out the collection that deviates from the issue of special symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A,REGEXREPLACE(A1:A,"(https?:\/\/([\w.-]+\/){4}).*","($1)")))
```